# How to clean all contents of a file from Terminal on Mac

Tags: terminal

How to clean all contents of a file from Terminal on Mac? I've been searching for this about a day (I don't want to delete the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a file with text content, there are  many ways to do it.

You can do either `> filename.ext` or `cat /dev/null > filename.ext`

Comment: It will stuck there forever. I don't know why

Comment: You can try the second option `cat /dev/null > filename.ext`, that should work.

Comment: Thank you. It finally worked

Answer (score -1):

You just need to write an empty content to a file, eg:
`> your.file`

Comment: it stucks on macos